# Hibernate Null-pointer exception when multi-threaded jpa read

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-batch, hibernate-mapping

I have an spring-batch job that reads from database using `RepositoryItemReader` then transform the results to a `Map` and then writes to elasticsearch the results. It works fine although a bit slow. So now I want to add a `taskExecutor` with a pool size of 4 to speed things up a bit:

```
        return stepBuilders.get("search-export").<AbstractEntityDefinition, Map<String, Object>>chunk(nemesisSearchProperties.getExport().getChunkSize())
                        .reader(reader)
                        .processor(processor)
                        .writer(writer)
                        .stream(reader)
                        .transactionAttribute(transactionAttribute)
                        .listener(chunkSessionReplicatorExecutionListener)
                        .listener(new NemesisChunkLoggingListener(indexName + " search export", nemesisSearchProperties.getExport().getChunkSize()))
                        .taskExecutor(searchExportTaskExecutor).throttleLimit(4) // <-- I add this
                        .build();
```

however the moment I add the task executor I get this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.IdentityMap.entryArray(IdentityMap.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.IdentityMap.concurrentEntries(IdentityMap.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.forEachCollectionEntry(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:1135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareCollectionFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:85)
```

and looking at the `IdentityMap` I can see this:

```
(1)     if ( entryArray == null ) {
(2)         entryArray = new Map.Entry[ map.size() ];
            final Iterator<Entry<IdentityKey<K>, V>> itr = map.entrySet().iterator();
            int i = 0;
            while ( itr.hasNext() ) {
                final Entry<IdentityKey<K>, V> me = itr.next();
(3)             entryArray[i++] = new IdentityMapEntry( me.getKey().key, me.getValue() ); // Here entryArray is NULL!!!
            }
        }
```

The exception happens on line (3) where `entryArray` is null. And I wonder how can it since the `entryArray` is checked to be null on line (1) and initialized on line (2).

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong on the Spring Batch side from what you shared. Since this NPE happens in Hibernate's code, I will let hibernate experts help you on this.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine can you please direct me how to write a reader for which every thread has a separate hibernate session, as per Christian's suggestion

Comment: I don't think we need to do this. An item reader should not be concerned about how threads are allocated. It's the step that drives the process and decides if the reader should be called by a single thread or multiple threads. If an item reader is not thread safe and should be used in a multi-threaded step, then it can be decorated with a `SynchronizedIteamStreamReader`.

Comment: That said, from the Javadoc's of `RepositoryItemReader`, I see: `This implementation is thread-safe between calls to open(ExecutionContext), but remember to use saveState=false if used in a multi-threaded client (no restart available)`. Have you tried setting saveState=false? I'm asking because I can't see from your partial stacktrace if the exception happens when dealing with the execution context or not.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine indeed I had not set the saveState=false. Now I added it and I get another null-pointer exception in a different place: https://gist.github.com/ptahchiev/b63d909fc8bb048d95df1c7376be43fe

Comment: That's again a NPE in hibernate's code.. In my initial comment I said I see nothing wrong with your config (I didn't have all these details at that time), but you can also remove the call to `.stream(reader)` since the `RepositoryItemReader` is already an `ItemStream`. That said, I would love to help if you can provide a minimal complete example that reproduces the issue with an in-memory db that I can play with and debug things.

Comment: Another thing worth trying is to make the reader `@StepScope`d.

Comment: Yes the bean is annotated with @StepScope, I also wrap the result with `SynchronizedIteamStreamReader` and still the same error :(

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine I've managed to create a project that reproduces the exception here: https://github.com/ptahchiev/hibernate-nlp

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look and get back to you when possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your reader, processor and writer looks like, but this looks like a concurrency issue due to sharing the `Session` across threads. Make sure every thread has a separate session.

See the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html

> There are some practical limitations of using multi-threaded Step implementations for some common batch use cases. Many participants in a Step (such as readers and writers) are stateful. If the state is not segregated by thread, then those components are not usable in a multi-threaded Step. In particular, most of the off-the-shelf readers and writers from Spring Batch are not designed for multi-threaded use.

It's probably best if you create a wrapper for all objects that store their respective reader/writer etc. in a thread local.

Java/Jakarta Batch gets this right. Reader, Writer, Processor instances are always per partition, so you never run into issues.

Comment: Hi @christian-beikov thank you for your reply. I am using a standard `RepositoryItemReader` from spring batch. Do you have any idea how to ensure a separate session for each thread?

Comment: @Christian Beikov What do you mean by `Java/Jakarta Batch gets this right. Reader, Writer, Processor instances are always per chunk, so you never run into issues.`? Does this mean if there are 10000 chunks, there will be 10000 reader/writer/processor instances created? From the framework PoV, we don't know upfront how many chunks there will be (unless you ask the user to provide the total number of items in some way), so are those instances created on the fly at runtime and manually allocated to separate threads? I'm curious to see how this is implemented and how it would solve the issue.

Comment: Instances in Java/Jakarta Batch are just "injected" and which instance is used depends on the scope of the bean. The default scope is "dependent" which I think will result in an instance per partition by default. So for every thread, there will be a separate instance unless you use a scope like e.g. `@ApplicationScoped`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I hope you agree with me that `So for every thread, there will be a separate instance` is very different from `instances are always per chunk`. An instance per thread makes much more sense than an instance per chunk, so I believe it's worth updating the answer because it's currently misleading. Having a reader/processor/writer instance per thread is similar to `StepScope`d beans in Spring Batch.

Comment: Not sure if StepScoped is the same. Like I wrote, in Jakarta Batch, the default is partition scoped i.e. for every thread/partition you get a separate bean instance. I updated the answer to "per partition".

Comment: Hi @ChristianBeikov I've managed to create a project that reproduces the exception here: https://github.com/ptahchiev/hibernate-nlp

Comment: As far as I understand Spring Batch, you have to use an intermediate class that contains a thread local reference to your readers/writers or change your readers/writers to move the state to e.g. a thread local.